# If $Ext(P,\_) = 0,$ then $P$ is projective

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

Trying to understand Bredon's proof (below). Please note that $G$ is an Abelian group.

So my confusion starts with $H_1(Hom(R,G_*)) \to H_0(Hom(A,G_*)) \to H_0(Hom(F,G_*))$. I understand that he is using Zig-Zag lemma:

$H_2(Hom(R,G_*)) \to H_2(Hom(A,G_*)) \to H_2(Hom(F,G_*)) \to H_1(Hom(R,G_*)) \to H_1(Hom(A,G_*)) \to H_1(Hom(F,G_*)) \to H_0(Hom(R,G_*)) \to H_0(Hom(A,G_*)) \to H_0(Hom(F,G_*))$.

Now because $F$ is projective $Hom(F,G_*)$ is exact, so $H_i(Hom(F,G_*))=0$.

$Hom(R,G_*)$ is only left exact, so can we find $H_i(Hom(R,G_*))$? I thought maybe  $H_2(Hom(R,G_*))=0=Ext^2(R,G)$, since G is abelian and similar for $H_2(Hom(A,G_*))=0=Ext^2(A,G)$ but is this correct and then what happens to $H_0(Hom(R,G_*))$?

[image: Bredon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's some confusion indeed: $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}\newcommand{\Ext}{\operatorname{Ext}} \Ext^2(X, G)$ is indeed trivial for all $X$, but this has nothing to do with $H_2(\Hom(X, G_*))$ ($X = R, A$): For one, $G_*$ and $G$ are completely unrelated; there is no group by the name of $G$ in that specific part of the argument. Moreover, $G_*$ is just *some short exact sequence* and you're not taking homology at the right index, so the group does not really connect to $\Ext^2$ in any meaningful way.

As for how to determine these groups, there's two ways to go about it:

1. *Use the long exact sequence.* Note that the homology sequence you wrote down actually extends by 0 to the left and right. Let us then see what terms we can eliminate using Bredon's arguments: All $H_i(\Hom(F, G_*))$ are trivial by projectivity of $F$, and $H_1(\Hom(R, G_*)) = 0$ as mentioned as well as $H_2(\Hom(R, G_*))$ by the same argument. Now all remaining terms are wedged between two zeroes each, hence all trivial.
2. *Invoke some knowledge about $\mathbb{Z}$-modules.* Namely, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module (which is just another name for abelian group) is free iff it is projective, and submodules of free modules are again free, so $F$ is free, $R$ is free as a submodule of $F$, and if you accept the conclusion of the proof then $A$, too, is free, from which it follows that $\Hom(X, G_*)$ is exact for $X = A, F$ and/or $R$, whence all homology of these complexes vanishes.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I am a bit unsure if I compute correctly here $H_1(Hom(R,G_\*))$ and $H_2(Hom(R,G_*))$. Here: $0 \overset{{\delta_2}}{\longrightarrow} Hom(R,G_2) \overset{{\delta_1}}{\longrightarrow} Hom(R,G_1) \overset{{\delta_0}}{\longrightarrow} Hom(R,G_0)$. In this case $H_0(Hom(R,G_\*))=\frac{ker\delta_0}{im\delta_1}=0$ because of the exactness and the same argument for $H_1$ and $H_2$, where for $H_2$ $\delta_3: 0 \to 0$. 

Sorry if this is super trivial; just want to make sure I am not making stupid mistakes!

Comment: @strugglingmathguy You do not have the indexing quite right: $H_i(\operatorname{Hom}(R, G_*)) = \ker \delta_{i - 1} / \operatorname{im} \delta_i$, so the group you're computing is actually $H_1$ (but the argument is correct). Then $H_2(\operatorname{Hom}(R, G_*)) = \ker \delta_1 / \operatorname{im} \delta_2 = 0$ also by exactness, but for $H_0(\operatorname{Hom}(R, G_*)) = \operatorname{coker} \delta_0$ you need another argument.

Comment: @strugglingmathguy To get the indexing right just remember the following two things: The differentials of a chain complex $(A_*, d_*)$ are by definition/convention indexed by the domain, i.e. it's $d_k\colon A_k \to A_{k - 1}$, **not** $d_k\colon A_{k + 1} \to A_k$ as in your comment. Secondly, $H_k(A_*)$ is formed by taking a _quotient of subgroups of $A_k$_, namely $\ker(d_k\colon A_k \to A_{k - 1}) / \operatorname{im}(d_{k + 1}\colon A_{k + 1} \to A_k)$, so to figure out the correct index you just need to figure out what term of the chain complex you're looking at.

Comment: thank you! your answers are really helpful!